# problema validando una sesion

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Muy buen día/tarde/noche. con toda la investigación hecha y dado el caso que el error persiste tuve que recurrir a otros metodos ya que cualquier cosa que se intenta no da resultados el nuevo codigo quedo asi:

```html
<?php session_start();
  $host = '127.0.0.1';
  $db = 'jobction';
  $user = 'root';
  $pass = '';
  $charset = 'utf8mb4';
  $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
  $options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
  ];
  if(isset($_SESSION['usuario']))
  {
    header('locacation: index.php');
  }
  $errores = '';
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
  {
    $usuario = filter_var(strtolower($_POST['correo']),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password = hash('SHA512',$password);

    try
    {
      //posible error
      $conexion = new PDO($dsn,$user,$pass,$options);
     /* $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false); */
    }
    catch (\PDOException $e)
    {
      throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
    }
    //posible error
    $statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :usuario AND pass = :pass ');
    $statement->bindParam(':usuario', $usuario, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $statement->bindParam(':pass', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR ); 
    $statement->execute();
    $resultado = $statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    var_dump($resultado);

   /* if($resultado != false)
    {
       $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
       header('location: mainpage.php');
    }
    else
    {
      $errores .= '<li>los datos estan incorrectos o no se llenaron</li>';
    } */
  }
  require 'views/login.view.php';
?>
```

puse en /* */ las ultimas partes del if y el else ya que ahorita estoy buscando si arroja algun resultado y no quiero que me salte a otra pagina :/
el html (queda igual) es este:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="" />
        <title>Inicio de sesion</title>
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/js/all.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="bg-primary">
        <div id="layoutAuthentication">
            <div id="layoutAuthentication_content">
                <main>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row justify-content-center">
                            <div class="col-lg-5">
                                <div class="card shadow-lg border-0 rounded-lg mt-5">
                                    <div class="card-header"><h3 class="text-center font-weight-light my-4">Inicio de Sesión</h3></div>
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <form action = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" class = "formulario" method = "POST" name = "login">
                                            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                                <input class="form-control" id="inputEmail" type="email" name = "correo" placeholder="name@example.com" />
                                                <label for="inputEmail">direccion de correo</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                                <input class="form-control" id="inputPassword" type="password" name = "password" placeholder="password" />
                                                <label for="inputPassword">Contraseña</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-check mb-3">
                                                <input class="form-check-input" id="inputRememberPassword" type="checkbox" value="" />
                                                <label class="form-check-label" for="inputRememberPassword">Recordar contraseña</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <?php if(!empty($errores)):  ?>
                                                <div class = "error">
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <?php echo $errores; ?>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                            <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mt-4 mb-0">
                                                <a class="small" href="password.php">¿no recuerdas tu contraseña?</a>
                                                <i class="btn btn-primary" onclick = "login.submit()">Login</i>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-footer text-center py-3">
                                        <div class="small"><a href="register.php">¿Necesitas una cuenta? Registrate</a></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </main>
            </div>
            <div id="layoutAuthentication_footer">
                <footer class="py-4 bg-light mt-auto">
                    <div class="container-fluid px-4">
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between small">
                            <div class="text-muted">Copyright &copy; Your Website 2021</div>
                            <div>
                                <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
                                &middot;
                                <a href="#">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Se darán cuenta que es de un login y no de un registro de sesión. El problema ahora es que cuando pongo un var dump me arroja esta vez un bool(true) pero en mi base de datos solo tengo una fila y no solo eso si no que cuando pongo otros valores aunque sean incorrectos parece que siempre me sale un bool(true) y me sigue sin arrojar los resultados de mi db, que por cierto ya cambio y ahora es solo estos datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí la pregunta que me sigo haciendo es: dónde está el error, ya que no sé ni siquiera si está conectada a la DB y no parece estarlo ya que siempre me regresa bool(true) ahora si no tengo idea de donde pueda esta el error :/

Comment: Ese bloque de PHP que planteas, ¿Es el único bloque dentro del archivo, o hay más código?

Comment: es todo el php q hay

Comment: pero ahorita que lo cheque hay mas archivos pero los importantes son el de registro, y este de login y ya :/

Comment: Dices entonces que estás teniendo problemas con la sesión, pero en ese bloque de PHP no veo `session_start();` Prueba añadiendo esa linea lo primero en ese bloque de PHP y me comentas si hay o no algún avance.

Comment: ya lo agregue y me sigue mandando bool(flase) lo cual no me esta arrojando los datos de mi DB

Comment: otra cosa interesante es que cambio el fetch por fetchall y me sale array(0) { }

Comment: Te sale bool false porque no tienes ninguna variable de sesión iniciada.

Answer (score 0):

En base a los comentarios proporcionados y una revisión del código, parece ser que estás utilizando el método `execute` de manera incorrecta.

[Documentación de PHP - PDOStatement::execute](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.execute.php)

Puedes solucionar ese problema de dos maneras:

### Opción 1:

Realizar la unión de parámetros por nombre antes de `$statement->execute()`

[Documentación de PHP - PDOStatement::bindParam](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

En la documentación tienes ejemplos de como hacerlo.

---

### Opción 2:

No realizar la unión de parámetros nombre, e ir por orden:

1. Cambiando los parámetros por `?`

La sentencia quedaría así:

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ? AND pass = ?');
```

2. Cambiar el array de datos para incluir **solamente** los datos a preparar y **respetando el orden de la sentencia SQL**:

La sentencia pasaría a ser:

```
  $statement->execute(array(
     $usuario,
     $password
  ));
```

Comment: pues no a cambiado nada sigue el mismo problema ya probe con las dos opciones y nada :/

Comment: Prueba a hacer un `var_dump($_SESSION)` antes del execute. También te aconsejaría que aunque no funcione, edites la pregunta, añadiendo los cambios de código que has ido haciendo y los resultados obtenidos / esperados. Que no funcione a primeras, no significa que sea un rincón sin salida, y donde unos no logran avistar una solución, otros pueden tener otra perspectiva, ideas, o incuso la solución en si,

Comment: ya coloque el var_dump($_SESSION) antes del execute y me sale un array(0) { } , ya edite la pregunta para que este actualizada pero el código casi no cambia :/

Comment: ya actualize todo a lo que tengo hasta ahora pero ahora me sale otro error diametralmente opuesto al que tengo ahorita pero con el mismo resultado: parece que sigo sin conectarme a la base de datos :/